# Filtering word digit from numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have created phone filter, where I filter out phone numbers and replace it with *.
I was trying to deal with exploits like numbers with words digit.

`4023one345233` should be considered as  `40231345233` and then should be blocked.

Here is my code:

```
    $arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
    preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $text, $matches);
    $arr=$matches[0];
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        $v = strtolower($v);
        if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
        {
            $text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);
        }
    }
    foreach ($words as $word){

        $pattern = '/^(?=.{8,14})b$\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );            
        $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
    }
```

problem here is:

my regex (which is specific for me to use) suppose blocks number with 12 digit. If that number comes with word `seven` so it will replace `seven` with `7` and last 4 character will be show as it is.

like

`40231345233` to `***********`

`402three1345233` to `***********233`

Any help so that I can blocke out entire number with such exploit?

**UPDATE1**

It should not change original text length:

```
$arrwords = array('0000'=>'zero','000'=>'one','000'=>'two','00000'=>'three','0000'=>'four','0000'=>'five','000'=>'six','00000'=>'seven','00000'=>'eight','0000'=>'nine');
```

**UPDATE2**

```
foreach (explode(" ", $s) as $word) {
    $num = strtr(strtolower($word), $arrwords);
    if(is_numeric($num)){ 
         $pattern = 'regex_above';
        preg_match_all($pattern, <$text?????>, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );            
        $this->pushToResultSet($matches);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces all your sample inputs with asterisks:

```
$arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');        
$nums = array("4023one345233", "40231345233", "402three1345233");

foreach ($nums as $num) {
    $n = strtr(strtolower($num), array_flip($arrwords));
    echo preg_replace("/\d/", "*", $num);
}
```

[`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) accepts an array of 'from' => 'to' pairs, so can be used to convert all of the names of numbers in the input to the numbers themselves. Then [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) simply replaces any digit with an asterisk.

Note that I'm using `array_flip` simply because `strtr` expects the key=>value pairs to be `'one' => 1`, etc., ie. the opposite way round to how you had defined `$arrwords`. In practice you should do this yourself, rather than using `array_flip`.

#### update

If the numbers are part of a larger string, you could [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string on `" "` and loop through each word. If the word [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), replace it with the same number of asterisks as in the original string, otherwise keep it:

```
$arrwords = array_flip(array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine'));

$s = "my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233";

$sanitised = array();    
foreach (explode(" ", $s) as $word) {
    $num = strtr(strtolower($word), $arrwords);
    $sanitised[] = is_numeric($num) ? str_repeat("*", strlen($word)) : $word;        
}

echo implode(" ", $sanitised);
```

Output:

```
my long STRING with some Numbers *************** *************
```

Comment: Yes, but if I understand well the situation, phone numbers are in the middle of a larger string.

Comment: @TomFenech: thanks dude, but here issue is original text length should not change. I changes litte in my quetion. would you like to consider this here or I should in other thread?

Comment: @cyclic That should be easy to deal with, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @TomFenech: thanks a lot Tom. But please see I dont want to convert it here. as in my question code, I am returning the matches only. replacing with astersik is managed there

Comment: after converting words digit to numeric digit, I have to validate it with regex. IF pattern matches in regex then I am return matched pattern back

Comment: but any how you mad my job smoother

Comment: @cyclic happy to help, I guess I still don't quite understand what you're trying to do and how that differs from what I've done. Is it essential that you use the regex in the question? Maybe some more examples in the question would make it clearer.

Comment: @TomFenech: actually her my main purpose is filtering numbers from text with exploits. For filtering number I have that particular regex. in this question I was trying to deal with one of the exploits of word digit. we are almost done, I am trying to see how can I remove exploits first, then match the number with regex and then pushing `$matches` to `$this->pushToResultSet[]` ...match length should be same as orignal numbr with exploits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54361/discussion-between-cyclic-and-tom-fenech).

Comment: @TomFenech: please see my `update2` code. what correction I need to return matching pattern of numbers to filetr out?